# Get selected value from tkinter combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am new to python and tkinter and I have the following issue. I am using tkinter to create a user input interface. One of the input variables is selected through a combobox. However, I cannot seem to retrieve the selected value and use it in the rest of the code. Basically, the last line of the following code does not "print" anything (i.e. the selected company name).

```
class ResModelInput:

    def __init__(self):
        param_window = Tk()
        param_window.title("Parameters")

        ttk.Label(param_window, text="Company:", font="Calibri 12").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
        ttk.Label(param_window, text="Valuation date (dd/mm/yyyy):", font="Calibri 12").grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
        # outputs
        ttk.Label(param_window, text="Valuation Year:", font="Calibri 12").grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)
        ttk.Label(param_window, text="Valuation Month:", font="Calibri 12").grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)
        ttk.Label(param_window, text="Valuation Quarter:", font="Calibri 12").grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)

        # variables to store input
        self.company = StringVar()
        self.ValDt = StringVar()

        # variables for output
        self.ValYr = StringVar()
        self.ValMnth = StringVar()
        self.ValQrt = StringVar()

        company_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(state="readonly", textvariable=self.company, values=CmpnTbl['CmpnLst'].tolist())
        company_dropdown.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(0, 5))
        self.company = company_dropdown.get()

        ttk.Entry(param_window, textvariable=self.ValDt,
                  justify=RIGHT, font="Calibri 12").grid(row=4, column=2, padx=(0, 5))

        ttk.Label(param_window, textvariable=self.ValYr,
                  font="Calibri 12 bold", justify=RIGHT).grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=E)
        ttk.Label(param_window, textvariable=self.ValMnth,
                  font="Calibri 12 bold", justify=RIGHT).grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=E)
        ttk.Label(param_window, textvariable=self.ValQrt,
                  font="Calibri 12 bold", justify=RIGHT).grid(row=7, column=2, sticky=E)

        Button(param_window, text="Calculate",
               command=self.param_calc, font="Calibri 12").grid(row=16, column=1, padx=(100, 5), pady=5)

        Button(param_window, text="Close",
               command=param_window.quit, font="Calibri 12").grid(row=16, column=2, padx=(100, 5), pady=5)

        param_window.mainloop()

    def param_calc(self):

        ValDt = datetime.strptime(self.ValDt.get(), '%d/%m/%Y').date()
        ValYr = ValDt.year
        ValMnth = ValDt.month
        ValQrt = "Q4"

        self.ValYr.set(str(ValYr))
        self.ValMnth.set(str(ValMnth))
        self.ValQrt.set(ValQrt)


Setup = ResModelInput()
print(Setup.ValYr.get()) #this works
print(Setup.company) #this does not print anything even though a selection is made
```

I have also tried the following but get errors:

```
print(Setup.company_dropdown.get())
print(Setup.company.get())
```

Comment: The line `self.company = company_dropdown.get()` will overwrite `self.company` to an empty string.  Changing the selection of `company_dropdown` will not automatically update it any more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the line:

```
self.company = company_dropdown.get()
```

which overwrites `self.company` to an empty string and it no more references the instance of `StringVar()`.  So changing selection of `company_dropdown` will not automatically update it any more.

Just remove the above line and change the last line:

```
print(Setup.company)
```

to

```
print(Setup.company.get())
```